# Coloring in images transparent part in imageview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

The following images brown color part is  transparent ,i tried coloring with the refrence http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-beginner-tutorials/digital-signature-application-in-iphone/,[image]

Is it possible to coloring only at transparent part in the uiimage view?

Answer (score 1):

The very simple solution is to have a `UIView` behind your `UIImageView`, make sure the `UIImageView` has a background set to Clear and then you'll be able to see what ever is in the background view through the transparent area of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Mike Ash’s [Implementing a Flood Fill](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-09-14-implementing-a-flood-fill.html) and [Optimizing Flood Fill](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2012-09-28-optimizing-flood-fill.html). You’ll have to swap out the NSGraphicsContext stuff for CGContext.